# useState does not update inside a function (even after it finished running), but it does outside of it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm witnessing weird interaction that i'm not familiar with and I'd love some clarification.

The state im using does not update inside the function, but does outside of it.

Currently I have a state defined like this:

`const [checkBoxArray, setCheckBoxArray] = useState([]);`

a function that is supposed to add or remove the row based on checkboxes id:

```
function changeCheckBoxStatus(e) {
  console.log(checkBoxArray);
  if(checkBoxArray.indexOf(e.target.id) === -1) {
    setCheckBoxArray(checkBoxArray => 
      [...checkBoxArray, e.target.id]
    )
  } else {
    setCheckBoxArray(checkBoxArray.filter(item => {return item !== e.target.id}))
  }
}
```

a table with checkboxes that are defined like this:

`<input onChange = {e => {changeCheckBoxStatus(e)}} id = formInfo.rows.length></input>`

where formInfo.rows.length is to keep track of which checkbox belongs to what row.
Now when the `console.log(checkBoxArray)` inside the `changeCheckBoxStatus` function runs, it always comes back as empty (as if it never added anything) but when I run `console.log(checkBoxArray)` outside of the function it displays the proper values.

It also never gets to the else part because `checkBoxArray` is always empty inside the function scope, which makes the if statement always true.

Also, I figured that whenever I add a new row, it saves the current value of checkBoxArray into the function.

for example:

first row is added > checkBoxArray is currently **0**

pressing 4 times on first row's checkbox > checkBoxArray still logs **0**

adding a second row > checkBoxArray will log **0** when first row's checkbox is pressed, but will log **4** when the second row's checkbox is pressed

Meanwhile the logging outside of the function works as intended.

Why is this happening?
Thanks!

EDIT:
Full component, as requested:

```
import {Fragment, useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import './AddPerson.css'
import {MDBInputGroup ,MDBInput, MDBTable, MDBTableBody, MDBTableHead, MDBRow, MDBCol, MDBBtn} from 'mdbreact'

const AddPerson = () => {
    

    const[typeDropdown, setCurrentTypeDropdown] = useState('');
    const[formInfo, setFormInfo] = useState({
        'lastName': '',
        'gender': 'M',
        'birthDate': '',
        'rows': [],
        'notes': ''
    })
    const [checkBoxArray, setCheckBoxArray] = useState([]);

    function updateFormInfo(property, value) {

        if(property === 'rows') {
            value = [...formInfo.rows, value]
        }
            setFormInfo(formInfo => {
                return{...formInfo, [property]: value}
            })
    }

    let columns = [
        {
            label:"",
            field: "checkbox"
        },
        {
            label:"#",
            field: "id"
        },
        {
            label:"Property",
            field: "prop",
            sort: 'asc',
            minimal: 'lg'
        },
        {
            label:"Value",
            field: 'values',
            sort: 'asc',
            minimal: 'lg'
        }
    ]

    function addToRows() {
            updateFormInfo('rows', {
                
                'checkbox': <input onChange = {e => {changeCheckBoxStatus(e)}} id = {formInfo.rows.length}  className='custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control mdb-checkbox' type='checkbox'></input>,
                '#': formInfo.rows.length + 1,
                'prop': typeDropdown,
                'values': typeDropdown === "Passport/Citizen" ? "Test" : "Test2",
            })
            
    }

    function removeFromFows() {
        console.log(checkBoxArray);
        // let removeIndexes = [];
        // let tempArray = checkBoxArray.filter((item, index) => {
        //     if(!item) {
        //         removeIndexes.push(index);
        //     }
        //     return !item
        // })
        // setFormInfo({...formInfo, 'rows': formInfo.rows.filter((item, index) => removeIndexes.indexOf(index) !== -1)});
        // setCheckBoxArray(tempArray)
    }

    function changeCheckBoxStatus(e) {
        console.log(checkBoxArray);
        if(checkBoxArray.indexOf(parseInt(e.target.id)) === -1) {
            setCheckBoxArray(checkBArray => [...checkBArray, e.target.id])
        } else {
            setCheckBoxArray(checkBoxArray.filter(item => {return item !== parseInt(e.target.id)}))
        }

    }
     console.log(checkBoxArray);
    return(
        <Fragment>
            <MDBRow center>
            <h1>Add Suspect</h1>
            </MDBRow>
            <MDBRow center>
                <MDBCol size='2'>
                    <MDBInput outline label="English Last Name" onChange = {e => {updateFormInfo('lastName', e.target.value)}}/>
                </MDBCol>
                <MDBCol size='2'>
                    <MDBInput outline  type='date' onChange = {e => {updateFormInfo('birthDate', e.target.value)}}/>
                </MDBCol>
                <MDBCol size='1'>
                <select onChange = {e => {updateFormInfo('gender', e.target.value)}} placeholder='Select' className="browser-default custom-select mdb-select">
                        <option selected value="Male">Male</option>
                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                    </select>
                </MDBCol>
            </MDBRow>
            <MDBRow center>
                <MDBCol size='2'>
                    <select onChange = {e => {setCurrentTypeDropdown(e.target.value)}} placeholder='Select' className="browser-default custom-select mdb-select2">
                        <option disabled selected value="">--Select An Option--</option>
                        <option value="English Last Name">English First Name</option>
                        <option value="Hebrew First Name">Hebrew First Name</option>
                        <option value="Hebrew Last Name">Hebrew Last Name</option>
                        <option value="Passport/Citizen">Passport & Citizen</option>
                    </select>
                </MDBCol>
                <MDBCol size = '4'>
                    <MDBInputGroup
                    className='test'
                    size='sm'
                    hint={typeDropdown !== 'Passport/Citizen' ? typeDropdown : 'Citizen'}
                    prepend={
                        typeDropdown === 'Passport/Citizen' ? <MDBInput hint='Passport' size='sm' noTag/> : null
                    }
                    append={
                        <>
                        <MDBBtn disabled = {typeDropdown === ""} color='mdb-color' className = 'mdb-btn m-0 pny-2 ml-1' size='sm'  onClick = {() => addToRows()}>Add</MDBBtn>
                        <MDBBtn onClick={removeFromFows} color='mdb-color'className = 'mdb-btn m-0 pny-2 ml-1' size='sm'>Remove</MDBBtn>
                        </>
                    }/>
                </MDBCol>
            </MDBRow>
            <MDBRow center>
                <MDBCol size='5'>
                    <MDBTable  small btn bordered>
                        <MDBTableHead   textWhite color='mdb-color' columns = {columns}/>
                        <MDBTableBody   rows = {formInfo.rows}/>
                    </MDBTable>
                </MDBCol>
            </MDBRow>
            <p>{typeDropdown}</p>
        </Fragment>
    )
}



export default AddPerson
```

Comment: @DBS I dont think that's the case though, because even after triggering the function multiple times, the value inside the function is always the value that checkBoxArray had when the row first initialized, regardless of the current state.

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your component ?

Comment: @Oriun Edited for full component, It might be a bit messy because I'm making sure it works before tiding up

Answer (score 0):

Unless the code you pasted had a typo, you need to return a value from `setState`

```
function changeCheckBoxStatus(e) {
  console.log(checkBoxArray);
  if(checkBoxArray.indexOf(e.target.id) === -1) {
    setCheckBoxArray(checkBoxArray => {
      // [...checkBoxArray, e.target.id]
      return [...checkBoxArray, e.target.id]
    })
  } else {
    setCheckBoxArray(checkBoxArray.filter(item => {return item !== e.target.id}))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with the different values of `checkBoxArray` doesn't comes from your `changeCheckBoxStatus` but from your `updateFormInfo`.

To make it simple, since you store your input in the `formInfo` state, the function you pass to the onChange is copied when you call `setFormInfo` and this copy is assign to the onChange. If you modify the original function without updated the state, you will not see the changes for the input.

Comment: No sure if I actually understand it, but I'll try to move the rows into a seperate state and try again, I'll keep it updated!

Comment: I moved the rows into a seperate state but it still does not work,It still keeps the value that checkBoxArray had when the row first initialized...
I'm clueless!

Answer (score 0):

There was something with the MDBReact library that caused the "frozen" state.
Unfortunately I could not pinpoint the issue, and to be frankly honest I wasted too much time on this problem.

I decided to use React-bootstrap (regular bootstrap) and just customize everything myself, and it works perfectly!